# Read song name into earphones

Tags: android, music, speech-synthesis

I almost always listen to music on earphones on the way. So I don't know names of most of the tracks I love, and it's hard to get the phone out of the pocket for each song to check the name.

Is there an app that will simply read the track name with pressing earphone buttons? No need to detect the song, only read the name and/or singer.

I’m using the S7 Android 7 device. All music is played offline using Samsung Music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Tune Announcer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwyer.tuneannouncer&hl=en) speaks the track name and artist when playing
>   music using the built in media players, or others that support
>   scrobbling.

Gets annoying after a while, but definitely announces each new song when it starts.

Comment: Finally a working app! However it doesn't fetch song name from samsung music but works perfectly with google play music.